# Trocar corretamente texto utilizando TextSwitcher

Tags: android, textview

Preciso utilizar um componente `TextSwitcher` com a intenção com que quando o usuário movimente este `TextSwitcher` para a direita assim como para a esquerda seja alterado o texto da mesma.

Para isso criei uma variável do tipo `String[]` e armazenei 5 valores, e utilizei o evento `OnTouch` no componente do tipo `TextSwitcher`, porém com o seguinte código que irei postar abaixo o texto não é trocado, continua o mesmo, até dar um erro de `ArrayOfBounds` porque não tratei o tamanho do array de Strings.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de trocar os textos?

```
    tsIntroduction.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Variaveis declaradas no topo da aplicação
                initialX = event.getX();
                initialY = event.getY();

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                float finalX = event.getX();
                float finalY = event.getY();

                if (initialX < finalX) {
                    pos =+ 1;
                }

                if (initialX > finalX) {
                    pos =- 1;
                }
            }

            // Varíavel pos declarada no inicio da aplicação para pegar a posição atual
            tsIntroduction.setText(descriptions[pos]);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, foi feito o seguinte:

Implementei a interface `OnGestureListener` do pacote `android.view.GestureDetector` e utilizei dois métodos principais para fazer a lógica:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
 }

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
     float sensitvity = 50;

      if((e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > sensitvity){
          pos += 1;
          tsIntroduction.setText(descriptions[pos]);
      }else if((e2.getX() - e1.getX()) > sensitvity){
          pos -= 1;
          tsIntroduction.setText(descriptions[pos]);
      }

      return true;
}
```

Sendo que a variável `mDetector` é do tipo `GestureDetectorCompat` e inicializa da seguinte maneira:

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
```

E `tsIntroduction` seria o `ImageSwitcher` e `descriptions` é o array de Strings que criei.

Não implementei a lógica para tratar o erro `ArrayOutOfBounds`, mas não é nada díficil de criar.